# Building OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, opencv, build

I'm using this: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
to build opencv on **ununtu 16LTS** for **Python 3**. 
On step 4 in **Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake** i'm stuck with typing in the right parameters. Could you, please check my variants, because i could only find folders and no files with suggested extensions. Also, shall i type a flag `-D` before each param?

```
         -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$HOME/anaconda3/bin
         -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5
         -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m
         -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a
         -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS= I dont have anything similar like path in the tutorial, but i have a "numpy" folder in /usr/include/python3.5!
   So what should i do?
```

Also, what shall i write in:

- `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`
- `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` (in this tutrial(previus step), o downloaded opencv-contrib. So should i type in: `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/vladislav/opencv/opencv_contrib`
- `BUILD_DOCS`
- `BUILD_EXAMPLES`

**ERROR:** When i run as it is told in the tutorial, i got mistakes like this: `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/vladislav/opencv/build/PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so" does not exist.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an example of my working cmake params (Ubuntu 16.04, Latest OpenCV, Python 3.5), but you need to adjust the paths by your own.

```bash
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \        
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.5 \    
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5 \ 
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5.so \
    -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

in my case opencv_contrib is in the same folder like opencv your cmake command starts from your build folder (`mkdir build` in opencv folder) so in my case I need to jump to dirs back and **important: refer to the opencv_contrib/modules folder**

Sometimes it's a little bit clearer to use the cmake-gui

`sudo apt install cmake-gui`